# Next.js routing with "next-connect" for subroutes

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router, next-connect

In my `Next.js` project, I created an express like `route->middleware->endpoint` pattern using `next-connect` package.

I have this route pattern:

```
/api/tours 

/api/tours/:id

/api/tours/top-5-cheap

/api/tours/stats

/api/tours/monthly-plan
...
```

In my `pages/api/tours/index.js` file I added a route to capture api/tours and all other subroutes like api/tours/top-5-cheap.
According to the docs this should work. But only api/tours works correctly and any request to api/tours/subroute gives a `page not found error.`Docs: [next-connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-connect)

```
import nc from 'next-connect'
const mainRoute = nc({ attachParams: true })

const subRoute1 = nc().use(mid1).get((req, res) => { res.end("api/tours/top-5-cheap") });
const subRoute2 = nc().use(mid2).use(mid3).post(endpoint2);
const subRoute3 = nc().use(mid4).use(mid5).use(mid6).get((req, res) => { res.end("api/tours/monthly-plan") })
    
mainRoute
    .use("/top-5-cheap", subRoute1)
    .use("/stats", subRoute2)
    .use("/monthly-plan", subRoute3)
    .get((req, res) => { res.end("api/tours") })

export default mainRoute
```

I want to be able to capture all requests to api/tours and api/tours/subroute from `pages/api/index.js` file rather than creating a file for each subroute
Any suggestions or helps are welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a `404: Page not found` error, because the page doesn't exist. Next.JS routing methods, means that `api/tours/top-5-cheap` will go to `/pages/api/top-5-cheap.js`. And if it doesn't exist, it returns an error.

**NOTE**: You can do this without the `next-connect` package with Next.JS file-based routing system.

#### Without `next-connect`

Here are two of my possible solutions

- ###### Create a new file and enclose the name in brackets (`[]`) to make it a [`dynamic route`](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes).

```
└── pages
    └── api
        └── tours
            ├── index.js
            └── [id].js
```

And use the `useRouter` hook or one of the [`data-fetching`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) methods, to access the dynamic `parameter`

```
// pages/tours/[id].js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return <p>Post: {router.query.id}</p>
}
```

- ###### you can send a request to the base route and pass the sub-route as a query

```
www.example.com/api/tours?id=top-5-cheap
```

And

```
// pages/api/tours/index.js
export default function (req, res) {
  // sub-route id will be passed in params object
  const id = req.params.id // top-5-cheap; ...
  
  res.send(`Requested ${id} api page`)
}
```

#### With `next-connect`

You can’t use Next.JS server with it’s file-based routing and the next-connect package, so you’ll have to use a custom server.

Read the official docs on [`Using a Custom Server`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server).

Remember you’ll have to [`disable the file-based routing`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server#disabling-file-system-routing) to work like you want it to.

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false,
}
```

Comment: You are defining `subRoute` and `mainRoute` in `server.js` file. But I don't have a custom server in my project. I am using Next.js's directory based routing. Can you please provide an example implementation.

Comment: I thought you were a custom server, I didn’t really mean `server.js`, I just copied the snippet you used in your question so I could pass the `top-5-cheat` as an id query @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOB

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOB. Did my answer solve the problem?

Comment: Here you go https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237814/next-js-routing-with-next-connect-for-subroutes